# what is the difference in system calls in thread creation and child process creation

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, process

How is the implementation of threads done in a system?
I know that child processes are created using the fork() call 
and a thread is a light weight. How does the creation of a thread differ from that of a child process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads are created using the `clone()` system call that can make a new process that shares memory space and some of the kernel control structures with its parent. These processes are called LWPs (light-weight processes) and are also known as kernel-level threads.

`fork()` creates a new process that *initially* shares memory with its parent but pages are copy-on-write, which means that separate memory pages are created when the content of the original one is altered. Thus both parent and child processes can no longer change each other's memory and effectively they run as separate processes. Also the newely forked child is a full-blown processes with its separate kernel control structures.

Comment: perfect this is what i was looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(Linux_system_call). thanks !

Comment: I would advise that you stay away from `clone(2)` and use POSIX threads unless you are into systems programming. Kernel interfaces could (and do) change in time. `pthreads` API should be much more stable.

Answer (score 1):

***Each process has its own address space*** aka range of virtual addresses that the process can access. When a new process is *forked* a duplicate copy of all the resources involved has to be made. After the forking is complete the child and the parent have their own distinct address space and all the resources involved within it.Naturally, this is an performance intensive operation.

While ***all threads in the same process share the same address space***, So when a new thread is *spawned* each thread only needs its own stack and there is no duplication of all resources as in case of processes.Hence spawning of an thread is considerably less performance intensive.

Ofcourse the two operations cannot and should not be compared because both provide essentially different features for different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Well it differs very much, first of all child process is in some way copy of parent program and have all variables duplicated, and you differ child from parent by its PID. Threads are like new programs , they run at the same time as main program (it looks like at the same time, due to slicing time of cpu by os ). Threads could use global variables in program, but they don't make duplicate as processes. So it`s much cheaper to use threads then new processes.

Answer (score 0):

Well you've read the important parts, now here's something behind the curtains:

In current implementations(where current means the last few decades), the process memory isn't technically copied immediately upon forking. Read-only sections are just shared between the two processes (as they can't change anyway), as well as the read-only parts of shared libraries, of course. But most importantly, everything writeable is initially also just shared. However, it is shared in a write-protected manner, and as soon as you write to the child process memory (e.g. by incrementing a variable), a page fault is generated in the kernel, which only then causes the kernel to *actually* copy the respective page (where the modification then occurs).

This great optimization, which is called "copy on write", results in child processes usually not really consuming exactly as much (physical) memory as their parent processes. To the program developer (and user), however, it's completely transparent.